# Using two or more set /p in the same line

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Im trying to make a script that the user need to fill 3 spaces in the same line.
Is it possibile?

For example filling a date: `25/02/2019` in this way: `day here / month here / year here`

Not line by line.

The normal way is that:

```
set /p "dd=Type the Day: "
set /p "mm=Type the Month: %dd% / "
set /p "aa=Type The Year: %dd% / %mm% / "
```

And the result will be: `22/05/2019`

But i want put these 3 `set /p` in one single line, filling only this single line.

I tried this way:

```
set dd=%%a
set mm=%%b
set aa=%%c

set /p "test= "!dd! !mm! !aa!
echo %%a / %%b / %%c
pause
```

Also tried:

```
set /p "dd=Type the day: " / &set /p "mm=Type the month " &set /p "aa=Type the year "
```

But unfortunatelly didn't worked. The second way worked line by line.

---

**Edit 1:**

Follow my final script to change the Windows date by batch command:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /d "%~dp0"
mode 42,12

:begin
cls
echo ------------------------------------------
echo          MUDAR A DATA DO WINDOWS
echo ------------------------------------------
echo( &echo(
echo  1 - Escolher a data & echo( &echo  2 - Retornar para a data atual
echo( & echo( &echo(
choice /n /c:12 /m "Digite uma op‡Æo:"%1
call :lab%errorlevel%


:lab 1
cls
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "BS=%%a"
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"
set /P "=Digite a data:     /    /     !CR!Digite a data:  " < nul

call :GetDigits 2 3 Day=
set /P "=.%BS% / " < nul
call :GetDigits 2 1 Mon=
set /P "=.%BS% / " < nul
call :GetDigits 4 2 Year=
echo/
echo/

    net stop w32time >nul 2>nul
    sc config w32time start= disabled >nul 2>nul
    date %Day%-%Mon%-%Year% <nul && (  
    echo Data modificada: %Day%/%Mon%/%Year%
    timeout /nobreak /t 2 >nul 2>nul
    goto begin
) || (
      cls & echo Erro ao mudar a data.
      echo( &echo( &echo(
      pause
      goto begin
)

:GetDigits HowMany FirstLimit Result=
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "digits=123456789"
set "%3="
choice /C "0!digits:~0,%2!" /N > nul
set /A digit=%errorlevel%-1
set /P "=%digit%" < nul
set "%3=!%3!%digit%"
for /L %%i in (2,1,%1) do (
   choice /C "0%digits%" /N > nul
   set /A digit=!errorlevel!-1
   set /P "=!digit!" < nul
   set "%3=!%3!!digit!"
)

for %%a in (!%3!) do endlocal & set "%3=%%a"
exit /B

:lab2
 sc config w32time start= demand >nul
 net start w32time >nul 2>nul
 cls & w32tm /resync >nul 2>&1
 echo Data atual retornada.
 timeout /nobreak /t 2 >nul 2>nul
 cls & goto begin
```

Comment: What's wrong with using, `Set /P "userDate=Type the date in the format DD/MM/YYYY: "`?

Comment: Hey my friend! Just to make the script more functional. (Belive me, even if i write `type in the date format` some people will ask me later `why it's not working`. Im trying to reduce my job the most i can

Comment: Whenever you use a `Set /P`, because the end user is free to enter nothing or anything at all, you should perform verification of their input before using it anyhow Better still use a scripting language, possibly [tag:powershell], which can verify the string as a legitimate date object.

Comment: The user is more likely to properly type `DD/MM/YYYY` than they are `DD MM YYYY` with a space between each value. `DD/MM/YYYY` is a reasonable, normal, expected way to type a date. `DD MM YYYY` is not.

Comment: @Ken White Some lazy people prefer write `260520199` and before find the error, they think is easier call me to solve the problem. So im trying to do it the better way possibile to really reduce my work, step for step :)

Comment: And that won't be acceptable if you're getting three separate variables on the same line either - you'll end up with one value of 2605120199 instead. Three lines, with a clear indication of what you want on each line, is more user-friendly and allows easier validation of the values. You're making things harder on both yourself and the users that are providing the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No comments... **`;)`**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "BS=%%a"
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"
set /P "=Enter the date:  DD / MM / YYYY!CR!Enter the date:  " < nul

call :GetDigits 2 3 Day=
set /P "=.%BS% / " < nul
call :GetDigits 2 1 Mon=
set /P "=.%BS% / " < nul
call :GetDigits 4 2 Year=
echo/
echo/
echo Result: %Day%/%Mon%/%Year%
goto :EOF


:GetDigits HowMany FirstLimit Result=
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "digits=123456789"
set "%3="
choice /C "0!digits:~0,%2!" /N > nul
set /A digit=%errorlevel%-1
set /P "=%digit%" < nul
set "%3=!%3!%digit%"
for /L %%i in (2,1,%1) do (
   choice /C "0%digits%" /N > nul
   set /A digit=!errorlevel!-1
   set /P "=!digit!" < nul
   set "%3=!%3!!digit!"
)

for %%a in (!%3!) do endlocal & set "%3=%%a"
exit /B
```

Comment: Just edited some lines to make it more clear for me! thanks! Follow my edit 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest to what you want. It requires the `choice` command.
There's still a blinking curser that is mildly annoying but you can solve that with third party commands if you wish.

```
@echo off

choice /c "1234567890" /m "__/__/__" /n
set x1=%errorlevel%
if errorlevel 10 set x1=0

cls
choice /c "1234567890" /m "%x1%_/__/__" /n
set x2=%errorlevel%
if errorlevel 10 set x2=0

cls
choice /c "1234567890" /m "%x1%%x2%/__/__" /n
set x3=%errorlevel%
if errorlevel 10 set x3=0

cls
choice /c "1234567890" /m "%x1%%x2%/%x3%_/__" /n
set x4=%errorlevel%
if errorlevel 10 set x4=0

cls
choice /c "1234567890" /m "%x1%%x2%/%x3%%x4%/__" /n
set x5=%errorlevel%
if errorlevel 10 set x5=0

cls
choice /c "1234567890" /m "%x1%%x2%/%x3%%x4%/%x5%_" /n
set x6=%errorlevel%
if errorlevel 10 set x6=0

cls
echo Date - %x1%%x2%/%x3%%x4%/%x5%%x6%
pause>nul
```

Comment: You also can't backspace with this method.

Answer (score 0):

If the system is a supported Windows platform, PowerShell can be called from a .bat file script to present a GUI calendar for date selection. Place the .ps1 script in the same directory as the .bat script. Adapted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/creating-a-graphical-date-picker?view=powershell-6

=== guical.bat

```
set "THEDATE="
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "%~dp0guical.ps1"') do (
    set "THEDATE=%%~d"
)

if "%THEDATE%" == "" (
    echo No date selected.
) else (
    echo Selected date is %THEDATE%
)
```

=== guical.ps1

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{
    StartPosition = [Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen
    Size          = New-Object Drawing.Size 233, 270
    Text          = 'Select a Date'
    Topmost       = $true
}

$calendar = New-Object Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar -Property @{
    ShowTodayCircle   = $false
    MaxSelectionCount = 1
}
$form.Controls.Add($calendar)

$OKButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{
    Location     = New-Object Drawing.Point 38, 200
    Size         = New-Object Drawing.Size 75, 23
    Text         = 'OK'
    DialogResult = [Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
}
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{
    Location     = New-Object Drawing.Point 113, 200
    Size         = New-Object Drawing.Size 75, 23
    Text         = 'Cancel'
    DialogResult = [Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
}
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
    $date = $calendar.SelectionStart
    Write-Host "$($date.ToString('MM\/dd\/yyyy'))"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Using powershell can be easier!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) directly from a [for](/questions/tagged/for) loop in your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), if it suits your purpose better:

Something like this may be adequate; the end user is prompted to enter the date in a specific format, and continues only when `PowerShell` recognises the input as a valid date:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Input="
For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In ('PowerShell -NoP^
 "$d=$Null;While(1){Try{$d=[DateTime](Read-Host 'Date [dd/MM/yyyy]')"^
 ";Break}Catch{}};$d.ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')" 2^>Nul')Do Set "Input=%%A"
Set Input 2>Nul&Pause
```

Comment: Hey mey friend cow! Thank you. Worked fine!